# Adding a column from one data frame to another with unequal rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a novice at Python programming (1-2 months of learning), and I'm currently analyzing some big lipidomics data for my PhD project. I'm trying to add a column from one dataset to a smaller dataset with a subset of matching values. I apologize if this question seems pretty juvenile.

I'm using alphabets to indicate the m/z values for simplicity safe

```
df1
m/z  Retention Time
a    0.187677
b    0.2345677
c    0.6574677
d    0.2233677
e    0.4568677
f    0.00945677
g    0.1865677
h    0.187677
i    0.222277
j    0.333677
k    0.1444677
l    0.187677
m    0.187677
n    0.187677
o    0.187677
**2005 rows x 10 columns**
```

I had to analyze **two of other columns in df1** (not shown) through a lipidmocis analysis software and got an output .csv file that filtered down to include relavent m/z ratios with their fold changes, p value, etc

df2

```
m/z FC ...
b   2.3 ...
d   4.5 ...
e   0.5 ...
f   2.1 ...
g   6.7 ...
m   0.5 ...
aa  2.1 ...
bf  6.7 ...
**1005 rows x 5 columns**
```

As you can see the number of rows are unequals and the matched m/z values from both files would not have the same index. I am trying to add the "Retention Time" column from df1 into the smaller df2 based on matching m/z values. The output would look something like this..

```
df2
m/z FC    Retention Time ...
b   2.3   0.2345677      ...
d   4.5   0.2233677      ...
e   0.5   0.4568677      ...
f   2.1   0.00945677     ...
g   6.7   0.1865677      ...
m   0.5   0.187677       ...
aa  2.1   0.456677       ...
bf  6.7   0.456677       ...
```

Once again, I apologize if this question seems juvenile. I have tried several methods of merging the data, but they have not worked :( Any tips, suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `pandas.DataFrame.merge` here:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'm/z':'a b c'.split(),
    'Retention Time':[1,2,3]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'm/z':'a b'.split(),
    'FC':[4,5]
})

df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='m/z',how='left')
print(df2)
```

[python tutor link to example](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf1%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'm/z'%3A'a%20b%20c'.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20'Retention%20Time'%3A%5B1,2,3%5D%0A%7D%29%0A%0Adf2%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'm/z'%3A'a%20b'.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20'FC'%3A%5B4,5%5D%0A%7D%29%0A%0Adf2%20%3D%20df2.merge%28df1,%20on%3D'm/z',how%3D'left'%29%0Aprint%28df2%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: I think this would work!! Thanks you so, so much! I have do have a silly question though.....When you write df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'm/z':'a b c'.split(),........... does one have to  individually type a,b,c individually in the dataframe code? I have 2005 m/z values in df1, and df2 would have 1005 m/z and Retention values..

Comment: `'m/z':'a b c'.split(),` is just a cheep way for me to make a list of test strings for my example dataframes. I was lazy and didn't want to write a comma and extra quotes for each string going into the column. The main point of the answer is the `df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='m/z',how='left')` part. just replace the variable names of `df2` and `df1` with whatever name you are using for your real `df`. Or do you not have this data in a DataFrame yet and need help getting it there?

Comment: I used df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='m/z',how='left') and the two dataframes got merged! YAY!!! However, the "Retention Time: column shows NaN for some reason. I checked the m/z data types in both data frames in float type. I'm trying to resolve this right now :/ However, the function overall seems to be working

Comment: As I mentioned over at reddit, trying to compare floats can be risky. Idealy the column you use for `by` should be `int` or `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `join`, this will bring all values from `df1` to `df2`.

```
df1.set_index('m/z', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('m/z', inplace=True)
df3 = df2.join(df1, how='left')
```

`join` works using the index of both dataframes as the key to match one row from `df2` to `df1`. In case you don't have the index as the mat

Comment: Thanks for the tip! You mentioned that join() uses the index of both dataframes as the key; however, the indexes from both dataframes do not have matching values. For example, in df1, the index of "b" is 1, however, in df2, the index of "b" is 0.

Comment: I added some notes on how to set the index for the desired column, the index is useful to assign values from other dataframes, however you can proceed with another solution like `merge` in case you don't want to modify the index.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)